# Einstein Localized Recommendation

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations

Reference Post: [Einstein localized recommendations not working](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/269714/einstein-localized-recommendations-not-working)

Extract from the reference post:

> Update; We fixed it by copying the exact Einstein attribute names as our column names in > the productfeed. Also you need both the Display prices in String datatype and the non-Display prices in float datatype.

I was trying to implement the localized recommendations. In the document, it mentions that the original price fields (SalePrice and RegularPrice) should be in float and the display prices (SalesPriceDisplay and RegularPriceDislay) need to be in String.

I wish to understand, where do we define the data type? When I add the custom attributes in the Einstein setup, it does not ask for a data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple Answer: You cannot define the data type.

Internally salesforce may have set SalesPrice and RegularPrice as floats / Decimal (19,2) or whatever but you can regard everything you customize into einstein as String.

Comment: Thank you. The question came since the document mentioned it specifically. Anyways....Thank you.