# Localized Fields in Einstein Catalog

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations

I am building a catalog for Einstein Email Recommendations and I need to merge data from different countries. I know that I need to have localized fields for Regular Price Display and Sales Price Display and that in these fields I also need to insert the currency symbol.

1. Do I also need to have localized fields for Regular Price and Sales Price?
2. Moreover, if I have two different countries, can I map data regarding one country to standard fields (e.g. ProductName) and data regarding the other country to localized fields (e.g. locale_xx-XX_ProductName)?
3. Finally, do I need to use the xx-XX format for localizations or can I also use a different format, such as xxXX? Using this one I already see these fields as locale fields in the Einstein Catalog.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your prices differ in the other country, then you should also add localized versions of Regular Price and Sales Price. If just the currency symbol is different, you don't have to. But nonetheless it is best practice to include all the fields for your locales (which makes the solution more future proof).
2. The standard fields will be used as a fallback, so any locale you don't include will display the standard fields.
3. You need to stick to the exact locale format, as Marketing Cloud won't recognize the fields as localized ones otherwiese. You also need to stick to the exact names, as follows:

Even tough there is a mapping which can be defined and the documentation isn't clear about this, localization only reliably works if the exact same names (case sensitive) as in the documentation are used. So for example `locale_en-uk_Productname` doesn't work, but `locale_en-uk_ProductName` works fine.

Here you can find the names for all the standard fields:

> SkuID|ProductCode|ProductName|locale_fr-FR_ProductName|locale_en-US_ProductName|Keywords|ProductLink|locale_fr-FR_ProductLink|locale_en-US_ProductLink|ImageLink|RegularPrice|SalePrice|OnlineAvailability|RegularPriceDisplay|locale_fr-FR_RegularPriceDisplay|locale_en-US_RegularPriceDisplay|SalePriceDisplay|locale_fr-FR_SalePriceDisplay|locale_en-US_SalePriceDisplay
>
> (Source: [Localized Recommendations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_localized_recommendations.htm&type=5))

This older answer of me could also be helpful for you: [Einstein localized recommendations not working](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/269731/36218)

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure a comment is the right place for this, but I also have troubles inserting the HTML code for the currency symbol in the SalesPriceDisplay fields. I'm populating the data extension via a SQL query and, since the currency HTML code contains a semicolon, the system gives an error. How can I do this?