# Einstein Recommendations with Local pricing

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations

Reference Post: [Einstein localized recommendations not working](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/269714/einstein-localized-recommendations-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1)

According to the reference post, Do we just have to add locale_fr-FR_RegularPriceDisplay & locale_fr-FR_SalesPriceDisplay in the Product feed data extension? If yes, Should we use 'locale' data type for the same?

Also, we get product feed file on daily basis on FTP, should it be also updated with those field?

Comment: it needs to be in the file you import into Einstein recs

Comment: Thanks for quick response, EazyE. 
So if I'm not wrong, there will be two fields in the product catalog file for Salesprice and Regular Price. 
Which is : RegularPrice/locale_fr-FR_RegularPriceDisplay and SalesPrice/locale_fr-FR_SalesPriceDisplay. 
and both the fields will have same number values or do we have to add currency symbol in 'locale_fr-FR_RegularPriceDisplay'